# Compression of binary arrays to overcome GPU memory limitations

Tags: c++, binary, cuda, compression, mask

I'm working on physical simulations on the GPU (CUDA) and struggling with the limited amount of available memory on standard graphic cards.

**The problem is as follow:**

I have a huge binary mask (> 30 GByte) which serves as a lookup table. To evaluate the validity of a specific variable I generate an index from the variable properties and check against the lookup table. This is done in parallel on the GPU for millions of variables simultaneously (only read access required).

To minimize the size of this binary mask to fit it into GPU memory I'm looking for compression techniques that still allow fast access by indexing the underlying data (best by a transparent container class who takes care about everything). Since the mask itself contains multiple repetitions of single bits, I would also expect that it is possible to achieve a high compression ratio.

**So my question is:**

Is there any known approach already available in nvidia's CUDA implementation OR
is there any other default c++ library which can do the trick?

Comment: Quick test - run your data through zip (command line) to see if you can achieve the compression factor you need

Comment: Whatever you *compress* you usually have to *decompress* to be able to use. And once you decompress you again take up the same amount of memory (+ probably a bit extra to hold the compressed version as well while decompressing). So, while compressed data might be faster to *transmit* to the GPU due to the smaller size, the memory you end up eventually using on the GPU is probably going to be the same or more (unless I misunderstood your question). Have you considered simply buying a GPU with more memory as the easy fix (might even be cheaper when considering cost of developer time)?

Comment: An A100 GPU has 40GB, and a single A100 GPU in a DGX-A100 can access up to 320GB of GPU memory directly, using the NVLink fabric in the DGX-A100. Access to the "local" 40GB can occur at over 1TB/s rate, whereas access to the full 320GB will be limited by NVLink bandwidth, which is about 300GB/s per direction (read or write) or about 600GB/s "bidirectional", combining the read and write numbers. You can access such systems and systems with even greater capacity/capability [in the cloud](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/announcing-google-cloud-a2-vm-family-based-on-nvidia-a100-gpu)

Comment: Is your mask sparse in 1's? Sparse in 0's? There needs to be something that makes it compressible in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments
Yes the mask is sparse. It represents a tissue model where zeros usually prevail.
@RobertCrovella Thanks! This is really helpful. I was already searching for cloud computing quotations. This might be an option.

Comment: This question should not have been closed. Asking what function in an SDK to use for a purpose is not the same as asking for "recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Run-Length Encoding

I don't know of any library that does this for you, but I can provide you with an idea of how to do this. Since your mask contains many repetitions of the same bit, a suitable approach would be Run-Length Encoding (RLE). The idea is that instead of encoding individual bytes, you encode the byte and its length:

```cpp
aaabbbababaaaaaaaa -> 3a,3b,1a,1b,1a,1b,6a
```

There are many ways to implement this in practice. I am working on voxel model compression and the approach that has worked best for me is to use the bytes `0x00` and `0xff` as escape sequences. So `[0x00, N]` encodes N zero-bytes, `[0xff, N]` encodes N one-filled-bytes. The remaining bytes stay uncompressed. Alternatively you could just use DEFLATE compression using zlib, I am sure there is a GPU implementation of this too.

#### Obtaining O(1) Random Access

The problem with any kind of compression technique is that it reduces data to a variable size, making random access impossible. To solve this, you would have to compress the data in blocks of say, 1024 bytes. You could then store a table of pointers to the start of each block, allowing you random access.

The obvious issue is that you can only keep one block at a time uncompressed and each time you access a different block, you need to decompress that too. This can be very expensive.

#### Settling for O(log n) Random Access

Another technique is to compress the data as an octal tree. The eight bits of a byte at a higher level represent which of the lower-level eight bytes exist and which don't.

```cpp
      0       0         1      1        // Higher-level bitmask representing
     /        |         |       \       // which bytes exist.
0000.0000 0000.0000 0010.1111 1111.1111 // Lower-level bytes.
```

Here, a `1` represents an existing subtree, a `0` represents a missing subtree.
We can optimize this tree down to just:

```cpp
      0       0         1      1
                        |       \
                     0010.1111 1111.1111
```

A zero-bit at a higher level represents all-zero data at a lower level, so we can just optimize those lower levels away. By arranging our data in a tree like this, we can access any bit randomly with O(log n) complexity. The advantage of this technique is that we have a lot of neighboring ones or zeros, those will get optimized away and turned into a single bit at some higher level.

Note that we can also optimize subtrees that are all-one as well. For that, we use the mask of `0x00` at a higher level. The `0x00` mask does not naturally occur, because it would have been optimized away as a single zero-bit at a higher level. So we can assign some special meaning to it.

Comment: Hi Jan,
this is really helpful!! Actually, my main issue was not to know how to articulate a sufficient search request on google (I'm not a specialist on computer science). Since for my purpose the encoding time itself is less important (if we are not talking about ages) and the focus is really on fast access the data, I consider the octal tree approach as quite interesting. Now I need to figure out if there is an efficient way to implement it on the gpu.

Comment: @adoering to give you a few hints, since I am working on something very similar to this right now: 1. The GPU just needs to do the decoding, encoding should happen on the CPU.  2. You can encode & traverse the octree either using BFS or DFS. 3. You probably want DFS because you only need a stack data structure. 4. You don't need to increase the size of your data to a power of two, you just encode fewer zero-bits in the upper masks.

Comment: @adoering another important trick is that the indices of the bits can be seen as octal digits. So the least significant digit tells you which bit of a byte is addressed, the next octal digit tells you which byte in a byte-octuple that belongs in etc. So you don't need any `<` or `>` comparisons when traversing the tree, you just use octal digits of the bit's index at each step. If this answer solved your question, please consider marking it as accepted :)